# Ionic Cordova Android - does using the Cordova buildConfig to sign also zip align?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I build and sign the Android version of my Ionic application using a a `build.json`file`.

So in the `build.json`I have

```
    {
      "android": {
        "debug": {
          "keystore": "MyApp.keystore",
          "storePassword": "mypassword",
          "alias": "MyApp",
          "password": "mypassword",
          "keystoreType": ""
        },
        "release": {
          "keystore": "MyApp.keystore",
          "storePassword": "mypassword",
          "alias": "MyApp",
          "password": "mypassword",
          "keystoreType": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

And then I will build using...

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --buildConfig=platform_build_files/android/build.json
```

This produces my signed file in one command. I have just (alarmingly!) realised I have forgotten all about the `zipalign` I see mentioned everywhere.

My question is, does the above also zipalign? If not, how can I also include this (can I run it as an npm script so I can easily call it all via `npm run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same concern as you and `cordova` docs do not cover this. I have only found, after reading your question, a GH issue which mentions that `zipalign` seems to be used. https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1077

Now, if you read the GH issue and the `zipalign` docs, it says that when you `zipalign` matters, before or after the signing, depending on how you sign the APK, e.g. `jarsigner` vs `apksigner`. However, if you read all the comments, it seems that Android Gradle Plugin seems to be doing all the work and cordova team does not know what happens under the hood and is probably the reason they don't mention anything in the docs.

The only thing that brought me peace was checking if the resulting signed APK is indeed aligned by running:
`zipalign -c -v 4 platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

If it succeeds, it will end with `Verification successful`. If it fails, it will end with `Verification FAILED`. You can exclude the lines with `OK` to see which ones fail:
`zipalign -c -v 4 platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk | grep -v OK` (or `| grep BAD` if you prefer)

Here is the interesting part now. I have verified the generated APK by removing the `--buildConfig` flag (so the output is not signed) and, interestingly, the APK is still passing the `zipalign` check. Note that I'm using `cordova 11.0.0` if that matters. I've heard that only cordova 8.0.0+ `zipalign`s, probably depending the Android Gradle plugin shipped with `cordova`, but I couldn't confirm it due to lack of documentation.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I am also using `Cordova 11.0.0` so hopefully the above also applies in my case. Yes it would be good if it was documented, buy you have given me some avenues to also explore further.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you look at cordova docs for Android platform, https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/, it does mention that you need build tools in your PATH for apksigner/zipalign, but it does not tell if zipalign is automatically invoked (you have to opt-in for signing the app, too). I have even tried to remove zipalign (rename it), generate the app and verify with zipalign, the APK is, surprisingly, zipaligned. I think Android Gradle Plugin also has zipalign bundled, but I haven't gone further, since I was happy that my APK is both zipaligned and signed.

Comment: Ok, it is all a bit of a black box :-) Thanks for all that information!